# Данные на разных языках

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Насколько мне известно, SQLite может хранить данные либо на английском языке, либо на русском. По-моему, для этого используется кодировка UTF или Unicode.
Как обстоят дела с другими иностранными языками?

Comment: Кодировка UTF (одна из разновиднойстей кодирования unicode) поддерживает любые языки. (см. http://unicode-table.com/)

Comment: То есть SQLite все равно, на каком языке хранятся данные при данной кодировке?

Comment: Ну да. Если там действительно UTF. Я просто конкретно lite не знаю, но это уже довольно давно везде так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*sqlite* позволяет задавать (с помощью [pragma encoding](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding)) следующие кодировки:  [utf-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), [utf-16](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), [utf-16le и utf-16be](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#UTF-16LE_.D0.B8_UTF-16BE).

любая из этих кодировок позволяют сохранять любые символы, описанные в стандарте [юникод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4).

юникод сейчас включает знаки почти всех письменных языков.

Comment: Спасибо.Стало все понятно после ваших разъяснений